# Op amp calculation

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image]

Assuming that the op amp and the diode are ideal (for op amp: infinite input impedance and 0 output impedance, for diode: 0 voltage drop):

D1 is open <=> $$V_i \frac{R2}{R1}>E$$

- case 1 (D1 closed):

$$V_i < E\frac{R1}{R2}$$

$$V_o = -V_i \frac{R2}{R1}$$ (It's a simple inverter)

- case 2 (D1 open):

$$V_i > E \frac{R1}{R2}$$

$$Vo = -V_i \frac{R2||R3}{R1} -E \frac{R2||R3}{R3}$$

---

How do you get the last relation (case2, Vo=...) ?

---

where $$R1||R2 = \frac{R1 \cdot R2}{R1+R2}$$

---

Comment: Gotta love those "ideal" 741 opamps.

Comment: Those "ideal" diodes are pretty sweet, too.

Comment: They are limited edition...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this homework problem from your **superposition** chapter? Short E, solve for Vo in terms of Vin. Short Vin, solve for Vo in terms of E. The final answer you have there could be simplified..